# How sum fields with the value true using aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Model.aggregate([
   {
    '$group': {
       '_id': '$id',
       'name': { '$first': '$name'  },
       'tof': { $sum: { $eq:["$tof",true] } },
    }
   }
]) .... // rest of the code.
```

I am trying to sum the tof (true or false) field, but only if the value is true, but is not working like the way i am trying..

What i am doing wrong here? How proceed?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of extracting and iterating, as you would in this case, documents you don't need using `$cond` you can just omit them from the find:

```
Model.aggregate([
   {
      '$match': {'tof': true}
   },
   {
    '$group': {
       '_id': '$id',
       'name': { '$first': '$name'  },
       'tof': { $sum: 1 },
    }
   }
])
```

However, since you are using multiple counts you need `$cond` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/ ) so here is an example:

```
Model.aggregate([
   {
    '$group': {
       '_id': '$id',
       'name': { '$first': '$name'  },
       'tof': { $sum: {$cond: [{$eq:['$tof', true]}, 1, 0]} },
    }
   }
])
```

Comment: i am sorry, i know this is not part of the question, but you seems to know what i am going to ask. What if i am using the $sum:1 for other think???

Comment: i skip this because i think that was not relevant, but i am using 'total': { $sum:1 } for sum all entries...

Comment: @DRX so you have multiple counts in your aggregation pipeline?

Comment: yes, i need sum the total of entries, and the total of trues values in the tof field in this entries @Sammaye.